# `ERROR: value too long for type character(2)` when running `\copy`

Tags: postgresql, psql

I set up a table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS details (
    CountyCode                  CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
    VoterID                     CHAR(10)    NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    NameLast                    TEXT,
    NameSuffix                  TEXT,
    NameFirst                   TEXT,
    NameMiddle                  TEXT,
    PublicRecordExemption       CHAR(1),
    ResidenceAddressLine1       TEXT,
    ResidenceAddressLine2       TEXT,
    ResidenceCity               TEXT,
    ResidenceState              TEXT,
    ResidenceZipcode            TEXT,
    MailingAddressLine1         TEXT,
    MailingAddressLine2         TEXT,
    MailingAddressLine3         TEXT,
    MailingCity                 TEXT,
    MailingState                CHAR(2),
    MailingZipcode              TEXT,
    MailingCountry              TEXT,
    Gender                      CHAR(1),
    Race                        CHAR(1),
    BirthDate                   CHAR(10),
    RegistrationDate            CHAR(10),
    PartyAffiliation            CHAR(3),
    Precinct                    CHAR(6),
    PrecinctGroup               CHAR(3),
    PrecinctSplit               CHAR(6),
    PrecinctSuffix              CHAR(3),
    VoterStatus                 CHAR(3),
    CongressionalDistrict       CHAR(3),
    HouseDistrict               CHAR(3),
    SenateDistrict              CHAR(3),
    CountyCommissionDistrict    CHAR(3),
    SchoolBoardDistrict         CHAR(2),
    DaytimeAreaCode             CHAR(3),
    DaytimePhoneNumber          CHAR(7),
    DaytimePhoneExtension       CHAR(4),
    Emailaddress                TEXT
);
```

I ran this command to import data from tab-delimited file `Detail.txt`.

`\copy details FROM Detail.txt;`

After a few seconds, the command line console spits out this error.

`ERROR:  value too long for type character(2)
CONTEXT:  COPY details, line 449121, column mailingstate: "273707216"`.

[Here's line 449121 copied into a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BvHF9VaX).

The error indicates PSQL tries to read the value `273707216` into the the `mailingstate` column, which is two characters in length. I thought PSQL would instead read `NC` into that column.

Why does PSQL read this line wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the line with tab characters specified explicitly

Comment: @zerkms Here's a pastebin. Check the RAW data. https://pastebin.com/BvHF9VaX

Comment: Yep, 17th column is certainly `NC`, odd.

Comment: Nonprintable characters?

Comment: Can you elaborate, @CraigRinger ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem resides in these fields of that row.

```
Hand Dr      \  Melbourne
```

The backslash in that data is immediately followed by a tab. To the copy function it looks like a \t, the double backslash might be treated as an escaped character and not a field delimiter, so that would "eat" up a column thus putting the mailingZipcode into the mailingState column.

Try to remove that backslash and try to re-import the row.